# Uniform electric field can exist or not?

Tags: electromagnetism

If it can exist, It must not change with change in frame of reference as its expression won't contain any frame dependent quantity. But we know electric field is frame dependent. Is it possible for electric field to be uniform?

Answer (score 1):

When we say 'uniform electric field', we mean uniform in space and maybe time, not really by different reference frames.  Changing reference frames can turn the electric field into a magnetic field.

Comment: "*Changing reference frames can turn the electric field into a magnetic field.*" - No change of frame can make the electric field zero.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Change of frame of reference will change the electric (and magnetic) field, but it can't disappear.

Comment: In some cases the magnetic field can disappear, but the electric field cannot. The reason is that the magnetic field is created by charges moving in space. So in their rest frame there is no magnetic field. In contrast, the electric field is created by charges moving in time. There is no frame in which time stops so the electric field cannot disappear completely.